# Removing postfix caused plesk to go down (Centos)

Tags: centos

I have a server (Linux Centos 6) where Plesk was installed and running correctly (except for the mail server which wasn't working for some reason).

Wanting to replace the default mail server (postfix) for sendmail, I ran the following command:

```
yum remove postfix
```

For some reason, it also removed all the dependencies:

```
git perl-Git plesk-core plesk-l10n plesk-mail-pc-driver pp-sitebuilder psa psa-backup-manager psa-drweb-configurator psa-horde psa-imp psa-ingo psa-kronolith psa-libxml-proxy psa-mimp psa-mnemo psa-passwd psa-turba psa-updates psa-vhost
```

Even git wasn't working anymore. I had to reinstall it.

However, I can't bring back my Plesk panel. I used to login at hostname.com:8443 but that page isn't working anymore.

My web server is still up and PHP & MySQL are still running fine so that's good news.

How can I resolve this? Will I have to remove and re-install Plesk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You already removed Plesk, so just reinstall it.

And, in future, be careful with `yum remove`. Inspect what it says it's doing very carefully before you approve it.